# Ubuntu 14.04,32 or 64 bits with 2 gb of ram?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, 14.04

I have an AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ × 2, with an Nvidia GT 220 and 2 GB of ram.  I am currently running 13.10.

Do you think it would be better to upgrade to 14.04 in 64 or 32 bits?

Thanks.

Comment: use 64 bit as your cpu is 64 bit

Comment: What the duplicate answer seems to hide in plain sight regarding memory consumption: There is the [x32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) that combines the speed improvements of x86-64 with the lower memory consumption of x86. So you should at least try 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend 32 bit. Ubuntu suggests that you use 32 bit if you have 2GB ram or less even with a 64 bit processor, so I'd choose 32 bit just to stay safe.